# sharepoint Draft Item Security (Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)) is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-server

i am created a document library and when i want to activate Draft Item Security for use approve feature and this option `Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)` is disabled for me !

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on content approval as below:

[image]

Once this is set to yes, you will be able to turn on draft item security